# Setting a button visibility depending on an action

Tags: android, permissions

I created a button in main activity to grant permissions. I want to set the visibility of the button to gone if the user still have the permissions and if not I want the button to appear again .
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Button.setVisibility(View.Visible);
    } else {
    Button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    OR

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Button.setVisibility(View.Visible);
    } else (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
    Button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks you really saved me 

Comment: No probs @AbdullahAli, glad to know I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the use of Bitflags and EnumSets for keeping your permissions.

Bit flags, commonly referred to as Bit fields are an efficient way of storing several related boolean values in a single primitive type.

From there you simply make a check for if that user has the permission bitflag set to “true” and then set the visibility based on that value

```
yourButton.setVisiblility(PermissionsEnum.canSeeButton? VISIBLE : GONE);
```

This is for user/settings specific permissions such as “client can view pricing” or “user has admin rights”

For android runtime permissions such as Send_SMS, Location, Internal File Storage please refer to @TPInc Report answer

Comment: Thank you I will look it up